# Image Rectification of Stereo Images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, visual-odometry

My final goal is to make visual odometry. For this, I am going to collect my own image dataset. But first of all, I am triying to do image rectification with raw images of [Malaga Dataset](https://www.mrpt.org/MalagaUrbanDataset) . The dataset is stereo images dataset. I already downloaded the malaga-urban-dataset-extract-07.zip file and I tryed to do image rectification with raw images. I used the [MATLAB code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/uncalibrated-stereo-image-rectification.html) :

```
path='C:\Users\Jasmine\Desktop\malaga_raw';
for i=0:2120
I1 = imread([path '\image_0\' sprintf('%06d.jpg',i)]); % left camera images
I2= imread([path '\image_1\' sprintf('%06d.jpg',i)]);  % right camera images
I1gray = histeq(rgb2gray(I1));
I2gray = histeq(rgb2gray(I2));
blobs1 = detectSURFFeatures(I1gray, 'MetricThreshold', 2000);
blobs2 = detectSURFFeatures(I2gray, 'MetricThreshold', 2000);
[features1, validBlobs1] = extractFeatures(I1gray, blobs1);
[features2, validBlobs2] = extractFeatures(I2gray, blobs2);
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features1, features2, 'Metric', 'SAD', ...
    'MatchThreshold', 5);
matchedPoints1 = validBlobs1(indexPairs(:,1),:);
matchedPoints2 = validBlobs2(indexPairs(:,2),:);
[fMatrix, epipolarInliers, status] = estimateFundamentalMatrix(...
    matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2, 'Method', 'RANSAC', ...
    'NumTrials', 10000, 'DistanceThreshold', 0.1, 'Confidence', 99.99);

if status ~= 0 || isEpipoleInImage(fMatrix, size(I1)) ...
        || isEpipoleInImage(fMatrix', size(I2))
    error(['Either not enough matching points were found or '...
        'the epipoles are inside the images. You may need to '...
        'inspect and improve the quality of detected features ',...
        'and/or improve the quality of your images.']);
end

inlierPoints1 = matchedPoints1(epipolarInliers, :);
inlierPoints2 = matchedPoints2(epipolarInliers, :);

[t1, t2] = estimateUncalibratedRectification(fMatrix, ...
    inlierPoints1.Location, inlierPoints2.Location, size(I2));
tform1 = projective2d(t1);
tform2 = projective2d(t2);
[I1Rect, I2Rect] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, tform1, tform2, 'OutputView', 'Full');
folder = 'C:\Users\Jasmine\Desktop\malaga_raw';
newimagename_1 = [folder '\i_0\' sprintf('%06d.jpg',i)]; % left camera images
imwrite(I1Rect,newimagename_1)
newimagename_2 = [folder '\i_1\' sprintf('%06d.jpg',i)]; %right camera images
imwrite(I2Rect,newimagename_2)
end
```

But It gaves me the error in 152th frame:

```
if status ~= 0 || isEpipoleInImage(fMatrix, size(I1)) ...
        || isEpipoleInImage(fMatrix', size(I2))
    error(['Either not enough matching points were found or '...
        'the epipoles are inside the images. You may need to '...
        'inspect and improve the quality of detected features ',...
        'and/or improve the quality of your images.']);
end
```

Except from this error, already the perious (from 1th frame to 151th frame) rectifited images aren't resemble with the orginal rectifited images of Malaga dataset. For example; If I show to you respectiely the 20th frame of Malaga Raw Image Dataset, the rectification result of the Matlab code that I used and the original rectifited image of Malaga Dataset :
[image: The 20th frame of Malaga Dataset Raw Images]
[image: 20th frame rectification result of the Matlab code]
[image: Original Rectificated Image of 20th frame of Malaga Dataset]

I know that I used the Matlab rectification code for uncalibrated cameras. But, it is already calibrated raw image dataset in Malaga Dataset. Another rectification matlab code is [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/rectifystereoimages.html#d120e166562) But the Malaga dataset images (or the dataset that I will collect) doesn't contain the Checker board in it. So, I couldn't understand that how can i use [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/rectifystereoimages.html#d120e166562) code with images that doesn't contain a Checker board.

I have three questions :

1. How can I solve the error problem that I wrote in the above?
2. Why the result of the Matlab rectification isn't resemble to the original rectification image?
3. How can i rectify the raw images with another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference most probably comes from the fact that you used estimateUncalibratedRectification() whereas the rectified images of the Malaga dataset rely on a proper rectification using calibration parameters.

In the [Malaga dataset](https://www.mrpt.org/MalagaUrbanDataset) webpage, you can find the stereo calibration parameters (e.g. [http://ingmec.ual.es/~jlblanco/malaga-urban-dataset/calibration/camera_params_rectified_a=0_800x600.txt](http://ingmec.ual.es/%7Ejlblanco/malaga-urban-dataset/calibration/camera_params_rectified_a=0_800x600.txt) .

Using this approach, you should get the same results.